# selectedItem in ui-grid 3.0.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm currently testing angular ui-grid 3.0.0. Following sample code from older version, the selectedItems should contains some object when selected. In version 3, it doesn't seems to work. Anybody have encounter the same behaviour?

Angularjs version: 1.3.11
Angular-ui-grid: 3.0.0-rc.16
here are some extract code from my controller:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {  };
$scope.mySelections = [];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    modifierKeysToMultiSelect: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    pagingPageSize: 25,
    useExternalPagination: true,
    useExternalSorting: true,
    selectedItems: $scope.mySelections
};

$scope.changeDelete = function () {
    $log.debug('Selection length = ' + $scope.mySelections.length);
    if ($scope.mySelections.length > 0) {
        $location.path("/EREditHospitalChange/");
    }
    $location.path("/EREditHospitalChange/LYNDA");

}
```

// mySelections.length is always 0.

He my grid declaration in html page:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-edit class="grid"></div>

<pre>{{mySelections}}</pre>
</fieldset>
<button ng-click="changeDelete()">Change/Delete</button>

[] This is what is visible in {{mySelections}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using the gridApi.selection. See documentation at http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.selection.api:PublicApi and the tutorial: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection

In your gridOptions, add this:

```
$scope.mySelections = [];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    modifierKeysToMultiSelect: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    pagingPageSize: 25,
    useExternalPagination: true,
    useExternalSorting: true,
    // Addition:
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(rows){
            $scope.mySelections = gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
        });
    }
};
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/u5pzISURTnvPBm9FyiLr?p=preview

Also you can remove the `$scope.gridOptions = { }` because it's perfectly valid to declare the object like you do right after that with the properties

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
$scope.gridOptions = your grid options

$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
     $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
}
$scope.delete = function() {
    var rows = scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
}
```

these or that way its in the $scope.gridApi.* if you try to get the ithe checkbox selections